# Search with multiple criterias in LiteDB : combine queries

Tags: litedb

Can someone tell me how to search data in liteDb using the following pseudocode ?

**Pseudo Code**

```
col = db.GetCollection<Product>("products");
string keyword = "1AS";

Query query;

if (condition1)
{
    query += Query.Contains("ProductName", keyword);
}

if (condition2)
{
    query += Query.Contains("ProductModel", keyword);
}

if (condition3)
{
    query += Query.Contains("Note", keyword);
}


if (query.Any()) //
{
    var data = col.Find(query).toList();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Query.And(params Query[] queries)`, like this:

```
var list = new List<Query>();

if (condition1)
{
    list.Add(Query.Contains("ProductName", keyword));
}
if (condition2)
{
    list.Add(Query.Contains("ProductModel", keyword));
}

...

if (list.Count > 0) //
{
    var q = list.Count == 1 ? list.First() : Query.And(list.ToArray());

    var data = col.Find(q);
}
```

Comment: sorry sir, when I run the app I get this Error, "System.ArgumentException: At least two Query should be passed" I'm missing something ?

Comment: to get this working it must check the item count: if(list.Count==1)
  {
   db.GetCollection<Customer>().Find(list.First()); 
  }
  else if(list.Count> 1)
  {
   db.GetCollection<Customer>().Find(Query.Or(list.ToArray())); 
  }